# Why does my Quick Action not show up in Lightning Experience?

Tags: lightning, quickaction, custom-actions

I have created a action to create a record on Opportunity object  and added it to the page Layout as well   but i am unable to see the quick action on the opportunity detail records

Can someone please advice if i am missing anything here

![QuickAction] [image: Quick action on the page Layout]

![Opportunity Record] [image: Opportunity details]

Comment: Does your profile have record type access to whatever record type the quick action may be using?

Comment: Hi @KrisGoncalves how do i know if i have access to that record type i am having system administrator profile

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It could be many things. Below is a general troubleshooting list for a quick action (QA) that doesn't appear on record pages:

1. Does the user have access to the object the QA is creating?
2. If it's `Log a Call` - does the user have `Access Activities` permission?
3. If it's `Send Email`, does the user have `Send Email` permissions and is email deliverability turned "on" where you're testing?
4. Does the user have record type access to the record type defined in the QA?
5. If it's a VF, Aura, or LWC QA - does the user have apex access to the controller (if one is used).
6. If it's a flow QA - does the user have the `Run Flows` permission or `Flow User` checkbox on their User record? Is the Flow activated? Does the Flow [use](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.ls_provide_flow_access_to_profiles.htm&type=5) `Override default behavior and restrict access to enabled profiles or permission sets` - does the user have relevant profile/perm set?
7. Is the page layout you added the QA defined in the page layout assignment for your profile for that record type of the record you're testing on?
8. Do you have a lightning page defined? Is it using dynamic actions? You'll have to add the QA to the dynamic actions on the lightning page itself.
9. Is the object you added the QA to a Case, Work Order, or User? This works differently in where the QA appears as noted in [Actions in Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.actions_in_lex.htm&type=5). Depending on if feed tracking is enabled, you may see the QA in the chatter tab - utilizing dynamic actions will let you put the QA where you'd like (see this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/347102/lwc-quick-action-on-case))

---

Below are more details on how to check each of the above

1. `Setup --> Profiles --> UserProfile`. Go to `Standard Object Permissions` or `Custom Object Permissions` to check it has create/update access.

[image]

2. `Setup --> Profiles --> UserProfile`. Under *General User Permissions*, there's the `Access Activities` permission that needs to be checked.

[image]

3. `Setup --> Profiles --> UserProfile`. Under *General User Permissions*, there's a `Send Email` permission. For Email Deliverability, go to `Setup --> Deliverability` and make sure *Access Level* is set to `All Email`

[image]

4. `Setup --> Profiles --> UserProfile`. Go to `Record Type Settings`, do you see the record type listed next to the object? If not, click `edit` and add it.

[image]

5. `Setup --> Apex Classes --> YourApexClass`. Click on `Security` and make sure the user's profile is added to the list.

[image]

6. Go to your profile and, under *General User Permission*, check if `Run Flows` is enabled. Otherwise, go to the user record itself and see if `Flow User` is checked.

[image]

For checking "override default behavior" - click on down arrow on Flow, select "Edit Access" and see which profiles are enabled

[image]

[image]

7. `Setup --> Object Manager --> YourObject --> Page Layouts`. Click `Page Layout Assignment` and confirm the page layout you updated is assigned for the record type of the record you're on (not necessarily the one you may be creating in the QA).

[image]

8. `Setup --> Object Manager --> YourObject --> Lightning Record Pages`. You may need to look at `View Page Assignments` or what is the `Org Default` page, but once you figure out which page is displayed to your user, click into it and edit it. On your highlights panel, do you see an `Add Action` button or an `Upgrade to Dynamic Actions`. If you see an `Add Action`, you'll have to add your QA there.

[image]

Comment: I have to acknowledge this is superb

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue but none of the fixes mentioned worked for me. After hit-and-trial, I found out that there is a `lookup` field on the child object (being created) from QA on the parent object, that didn't had the **edit** access on the profile. After giving the required access the QA started appearing (lookup field is **not** required yet the QA disappeared).

- Go to the affected profile > Object settings > Select Object > Field Permissions > Make sure that the field has `edit` access on the profile.

[image]