# Quick action not visible to users

Tags: sales-cloud, lightning-quickaction

I have a lightning quick action on record page layout that's visible to my admin but not visible to other users. It calls an aura component and apex.

The user profile has access to the apex classes.

What other permissions could be missing?

Comment: You could double check the page layout assignments - that your admin and standard users have the same one assigned, and same for the Lightning record page assignments (that they are looking at the same one). Is the action itself missing, or just hitting an error?

Comment: check if you have dynamic actions and that specific quick action has conditional visibility set

Comment: Check-in record page/Flexipage by editing from setup and make sure there are not any visibility criteria for it.

Comment: @cropredy no dynamic actions configured yet, I was thinking of migrating but wonder if it will bypass whatever the issue is at the moment.

Comment: if quick action is for Create Record and user doesn't have CRUD on that object

Comment: the user has crud on the object :/ it's not this..

Comment: i assume you've read: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/355035/2602 ?