# why my quick action doesn' appear in my page layout?

Tags: quickaction

I have a problem.
I created a new action in the account object , and I add it in the page layout of the record type which is billto , but the action doesn't show up in my page layout.
Can you help me.
[image]

as you can see , here in the lightning app builder, it appears[image]

but in the page layout as you remark it doesn't show up
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community. Did you go through this [q&a](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/355028/why-does-my-quick-action-not-show-up-in-lightning-experience?rq=1) ?

Comment: What does that Quick action do? Does it call any standard action or custom?

Comment: @NagendraSingh, it calls a standard action

Comment: @LeilaMed Can you explain what is that standard action? And check if user has permission to do that?

Comment: Yes I checked and eveything in this link https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/355028/why-does-my-quick-action-not-show-up-in-lightning-experience
but the action still doesn't show up.

Comment: @NagendraSingh, in the action , i create a record and in the target object i called visit report and in the record type i called core visit report which is aready created in visit report object