# LWC as Quick Action on Case Object with Feed Tracking enabled

Tags: lightning-web-components, quickaction, lightning-quickaction, summer-21

I have created a Quick Action using a LWC Component. I have placed the necessary XML targets as well.

The Action is placed on the Case Object which has Feed Tracking enabled. My page also has the Chatter component.

When I place the Quick Action in the Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions section it is still not visible even in chatter tab.
If I disable Feed Tracking then it is available at the top.

There is a similar question [LWC Quick Action on Case](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/347102/lwc-quick-action-on-case) -- but this doesn't state that such QA won't be visible even in chatter tab.

Any ideas?

Comment: Exactly my issue. Were you able to resolve it? Turning nuts here.

Comment: I was not able to, what I ended up doing was wrapping the component in Aura and then placing it.

Comment: Did you place the Aura in via custom action and that worked or directly on the record page? Cause we do have Aura custom actions,that show as expected on the Case Chatter. It's just LWC, that's not showing.